# Websites to perform performance testing

Tags: performance, web-application, web-service

I am starting learning in performance testing and tried to search about free open websites to perform performance in it. Can any one give me URLs for websites like this?

Comment: I doubt there are such web sites.That wouldn't scale.

Comment: If you are learning, you don't need to use many virtual users, and you could start analyzing your results with just 5 of them. _Any_ webpage would work for that goal, but if you cannot measure any metric on the server side, you will miss one of the most important features of performance testing. Why don't you try to stress your own test site?

@AdrianHHH Not a duplicate, Selenium is intended for functional testing, not performance.

Comment: Can you expend your question with what you have already found from your own research and what requirements you have for this website to offer?

Comment: @Johnbo The suggested duplicate is about finding websites to test with. Whilst the asker wants to use Selenium the question is general and so are the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Public websites do not want you to run your performance test against them. In fact, there is a name for that situation: it's called an **attack**, and you could get into legal trouble for it.

If you want to run a performance test, set up your own website.  (For your purposes, you can probably run the web server on the same machine as your test code.)